# How to create table with latest date per Job number? SQl

Tags: sql

Currently the code below has all the dates associated with a job number using three tables from a database that ties together with a column called "ID"

```
SELECT  LoadId.JobNo, LoadId.YearMonth, LoadId.Phase, JobCost.Depth, 
                JobCost.UOM, JobCost.CostCode, JobCost.CostCodeDesc, CostCategory.Category, 
                CostCategory.CurrentBudget,

FROM  CostCategory INNER JOIN
      JobCost ON CostCategory.JobCostID = JobCost.ID INNER JOIN
      LoadIdentity ON JobCost.LoadIdentityID = LoadIdentity.ID  

GROUP BY JobNo,YearMonth,Phase, Depth, UOM, JobCost.CostCode, CostCodeDesc, Category, CostCategory.CurrentBudget
```

How would I change the code that will only show the latest dates for each job number and keep all the same columns? The column for dates is "YearMonth"

Comment: What database? What is your date column (yearmonth?)

Comment: The date column is year month. I am just manipulating 3 system tables from SQL SMS

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 more subquery to join -

```
SELECT  LoadId.JobNo,
        L2.YearMonth,
        LoadId.Phase, JobCost.Depth, 
                JobCost.UOM, JobCost.CostCode, JobCost.CostCodeDesc, CostCategory.Category, 
                CostCategory.CurrentBudget,

FROM  CostCategory INNER JOIN
      JobCost ON CostCategory.JobCostID = JobCost.ID INNER JOIN
      LoadIdentity ON JobCost.LoadIdentityID = LoadIdentity.ID  
INNER JOIN (SELECT JobNo,
                   MAX(YearMonth)
            FROM LoadIdentity
            GROUP BY JobNo) L2 ON L2.JobNo = LoadIdentity.JobNo 


GROUP BY JobNo,YearMonth,Phase, Depth, UOM, JobCost.CostCode, CostCodeDesc, Category, CostCategory.CurrentBudget
```